# Guice startup time on Google App Engine 1.6.4

Tags: java, google-app-engine, guice

I'm using Guice 3 on Google App Engine 1.6.4. Today, I saw something bad on my startup time. My application (local launching) took 12 sec to start.

I got one `ServletModule` where I'm writing all my bindings in the `configureServlets` method.
When I left this method empty, my application take 3 sec to start.

This method contains ~30 binding, 3 MultiBinder and 1 mapBinder...

- Is it a normal starting time ? (~9s)
- How to profile Guice processing ? (log,etc..)
- Is there some good practices to optimize Guice startup ?

Thanks!

Comment: I wonder if normal Java profiling techniques would tell you how much of this is Guice overhead and how much of it is the cost of constructing the bindings in any event.  Also, [LazySingleton](http://groups.google.com/group/google-guice/browse_thread/thread/e34e475609c2cec4) might help spread out initializations to when they're actively needed.

Comment: The actual code would help in figuring out why it takes so much time.

Comment: Damn, I just switched to Google App Engine 1.6.3 and now it took 4sec... It's a Google App Engine 1.6.4 issue... Somebody know why ?

Comment: Where is the time spent?

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen - between `configureServlets` end and Google App Engine "com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl start", I can't tell you more (I don't know how to profile Guice processing..)

Comment: Are you doing any heavy work in your `configureServlets` method? I'm not an expert on `ServletModule`s but in Guice in general, constructing an `Injector` is fast, but if a module does heavy work in a `configure` method (or binds expensive-to-create eager singletons), that slows down the construction. See: http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/ModulesShouldBeFastAndSideEffectFree

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switching to `Google App Engine` `1.6.3` or `1.6.5` solve the problem. It seems that it's a `Google App Engine` `1.6.4` issue.
Thanks for your help !